# When scan remote hbase table using Happybase, 'Tsocket read 0 bytes Error' happens

Tags: python, linux, sockets, hbase, happybase

I'm trying to scan remote HBASE table which has more than 1,000,000,000 rows. After scan, using scanned rows, Try to make csv file using in hdfs.

I tried almost 3 weeks to solve it But i can't.

[In this way i scan data and make csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ojZN.png)

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psC8R.png)

[source of /host/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/thriftpy/transport/socket.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlxM2.png)

[source of /host/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/thriftpy/transport/socket.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBUEC.png)

==> *I have tried compat protocol , increase network tcp memory buffer, increase time out configuration, setting 1 to 10000 batch size in scan parameter etc..*

But it works well almost for 30 minutes,But suddenly error happens. 
Almost 1/50 times it finishes well.(works well without any error)
Please helps me. I tried to find the cause of Error. But i can't get it.

**Anybody knows how to solve it?**

**This is my code**

```
import sys
print ("--sys.version--")
print (sys.version)
from pyhive import hive
import csv
import os
import happybase
import time
import subprocess
import datetime
import chardet
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


csv_list=[]

col=[]
def conn_base():
    print('conn_base starts')


    #SETTING CONNECTION AND CONFIGURATION
    conn=happybase.Connection('13.xxx.xxx.xxx',port=9090)
    table=conn.table(b'TEMP_TABLE')

    #ITERATE DATA AND MAKE CSV FILE PER 100,000 RECORD. AND TAKE A TIME TO SLEEP PER 500000
    tmp=[]
    print('LET\'S MAKE CSV FILE FROM HBASE')
    index=0
    st=0
    global csv_list
    for row_key, data in table.scan():
        try:
           if (st%1000000==0):
                time.sleep(30)
                print("COUNT: ",st)
            if (st%500000==0):

               print("CHANGE CSV _FILE")
                index+=1
                ta_na='TEMP_TABLE'+str(index)+'_version.csv'
                csv_list.append(ta_na)

            st+=1
            with open('/home/host01/csv_dir/TEMP_TABLE/'+csv_list[index-1] ,'a') as f:
                tmp=[]
                tmp.append(data[b'CF1:XXXXX'].decode())
                tmp.append(data[b'CF1:YYYYY'].decode())
                tmp.append(data[b'CF1:DDDDD'].decode())
                tmp.append(data[b'CF1:SSSSS'].decode())
                tmp.append(data[b'CF1:GGGGG'].decode())
                tmp.append(data[b'CF1:HHHHH'].decode())
                tmp.append(data[b'CF1:QQQQQ'].decode())
                tmp.append(data[b'CF1:WWWWWW'].decode())
                tmp.append(data[b'CF1:EEEEE'].decode())
                tmp.append(data[b'CF1:RRRRR'].decode())


                f.write(",".join(tmp)+'\n')
                tmp=[]

        except:
            pass


        #PUT CSV FILES TO HDFS.
        st=1
        for i in range(len(csv_list)):
            try:
                st+=1
                cmd="hdfs dfs -put /home/host01/csv_dir/TEMP_TABLE"+str(csv_list[i])+" /user/hive/warehouse/TEMP_TABLE/"
                subprocess.call(cmd,shell=True)
                if (st%50==0):
                    time.sleep(5)


            except:
                pass
        cmd="hdfs dfs -put /home/host01/csv_dir/TEMP_TABLE/*.csv  /user/hive/warehouse/TEMP_TABLE/"
        subprocess.call(cmd,shell=True)

        print("PUT ALL CSV FILES TO HDFS")
        conn.close()
```

Comment: please share the code instead of screenshot

Comment: sorry i'm not used to posting So i had some mistake. I shared my code! please give me any solution thank u for answering me!

Comment: Are you checking for errors on the server side? Is the HBase thrift server always up? If it works at first and then stops, maybe worth digging through the server logs. Not sure if these logs would automatically be included in the default logger settings, so make sure they are.

Comment: Thanks for answer. u means check server side Hbase thrift log. But i couldn't find any error logs. I think there are many error realted to Tsocket read 0 bytes But there isnt't any solution or causes for therm

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the HBase Thrift server is up and running. You can run thrift server with following command:

```
hbase-daemon.sh start thrift [ -p 9090 ]
```

If you want to specify a port number, use -p. Default port is `9090`

Answer (score 0):

you are making it more complicated looking at the code above, it is just few simple steps

1. Make sure Hbase Thrift is up and running.(use the command above suggested by)
2. Get webHdfs enables in HDFS setting files.
3. From hdfs package use insecure client class(if not kerberos authenticated) to directly write files to HDFS(very simple)